# How is deadlock occuring in the below code?

Tags: concurrency, deadlock

I am trying to understand `deadlock` from Oracle's website [deadlock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html) but not sure why & when does two custom threads goes into deadlock condition.

```
package com.geekthread.java.threads;

public class DeadLock {

static class Friend {
    private final String name;
    public Friend(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public  synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s"
            + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
            this.name, bower.getName());

        bower.bowBack(this);
    }
    public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s"
            + " has bowed back to me!%n",
            this.name, bower.getName());
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Friend alphonse =
        new Friend("Alphonse");
    final Friend gaston =
        new Friend("Gaston");
         //holds lock for alphonse            
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
    }).start();
    //holds lock for gastone
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
    }).start();
}
}
}
```

---

Please correct my understanding of the above program:-

1.)  Holds lock for alphonse

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
        }).start();
```

2.) Holds lock for gastone

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
            }).start();
```

---

I have tried to remove synchronized keyword from the bowback that doesn't ends in a deadlock situation i.e. the program execution completes and program terminates after execution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every object has a lock associated with it, also known as an implicit lock or monitor lock. When `synchronized` is used on a method as in your example, the thread will try to take the lock associated with that method's object. So the thread that runs `alphonse.bow(gaston);` will take the lock associated with the alphonse object.

At roughly the same time, the thread that runs `gaston.bow(alphonse);` will take the lock associated with the gaston object.

So you have the alphonse thread holding the alphonse object's lock and the gaston thread holding the gaston object's lock.

When alphonse now tries to execute `bower.bowBack(this);`, note that 'bower' refers to the gaston object. So alphonse is trying to execute the `bowBack` method of the gaston object. Since the bowBack method is synchronized, alphonse needs to get the gaston object lock to proceed. But of course the gaston thread already has the gaston object lock!

So alphonse is trying to execute gaston's bowBack method, but can't because it can't get the gaston object lock.

At the same time, gaston has the same problem. He needs to call alphonse's bowBack method, but the alphonse thread already has the alphonse object lock.

So each thread has one lock and is trying to get the lock that the other thread already has and neither can proceed - a classic deadlock scenario..

Edit: Removing 'synchronized' from `bowBack` prevents the deadlock, as you discovered, because now there is nothing preventing the alphonse thread from calling gaston's `bowBack` method - alphonse no longer needs to obtain the gaston object lock that gaston is holding. The same logic applies in reverse to gaston, who can also proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitly not an expert in Java but my guess would be:

Since the class Friend is static, the methods of class Friend are static. Thus those methods lock the class itself and not the objects of the class.

This should provide more insight: [8.4.3.6, 'synchronized Methods'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)

Comment: This is wrong : "Since the class Friend is static, the methods of class Friend are static" The class is static just so we can have multiple classes in the same file.  The deadlock would still happen if `Friend` was in its own `Friend.java` file and not static

Comment: @dkatzel Thanks. Wasn't aware of the static class concept of java.